# Dependencies in pom.xml profiles

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, pom.xml

My problem is when I'm adding dependencies to profiles, everything in code gets "Cannot resolve". What is wrong with that pom?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>aaa</groupId>
<artifactId>zzz</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>test</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            </dependency>

           ... more dependencies...
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>test</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.196</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And one more question - if I have profiles, can some of dependencies be without any profile to be a part of each profile? Thanks for answer.

Comment: You have to _activate_ a profile if you want to use it. But why having dependencies in a profile when you actually need them in your code?

Comment: I paste wrong pom, it's edited now. :) I want to have other database in tests.

Comment: And I have spring.profiles.active=dev in application.properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have dependencies inside and outside of profiles. If you want to use a profile, you need to *activate* it, either from the command line or through some activation trigger like a file.

Comment: Ok, I understand that I can activate profile when I run for example mvn clean install -P dev and when my tests are running, the profile is changing, but in IntelliJ the whole code has "Cannot resolve".

Comment: You probably need to tell IntelliJ which profiles to activate in the Workspace (in Eclipse, the m2e plugin has options for that).